# ThemeData is Undifined class while material.dart is imported

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

ThemeData appTheme() {
  const Color colorWhite = Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 1);
  const Color colorButton = Color.fromRGBO(97, 120, 140, 1);
  const Color colorSmoothDark = Color.fromRGBO(97, 120, 140, 1);
  const Color colorDark = Color.fromRGBO(60, 78, 90, 1);
  return ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: colorDark,
      centerTitle: true,
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: colorWhite,
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: const TextTheme(
      headlineLarge: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 26,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      headlineMedium: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      headlineSmall: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      titleLarge: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      titleMedium: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      titleSmall: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      bodyLarge: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      bodyMedium: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
      bodySmall: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: colorWhite,
      ),
    ),
    buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
      buttonColor: colorButton,
    ),
    colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
      primary: Color.fromRGBO(97, 120, 140, 1),
      onPrimary: Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 1),
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      secondary: Color.fromRGBO(60, 78, 90, 1),
      onSecondary: Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 1),
      error: Colors.red,
      onError: Color.fromRGBO(60, 78, 90, 1),
      background: Color.fromRGBO(186, 203, 217, 1),
      onBackground: Color.fromRGBO(60, 78, 90, 1),
      surface: Color.fromRGBO(143, 173, 191, 1),
      onSurface: Color.fromRGBO(60, 78, 90, 1),
    ),
  );
}
```

This is my code which was working smoothly but It's not working right now. I created a package in different project and now all my projects have me the same error which is:

```
``ZInvalid depfile: D:\development\project\alpando_art\.dart_tool\flutter_build\52a8fa083cfe2f6c474dbacd641188fe\kernel_snapshot.d
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'flutter_login' in 'package:flutter_login/app.dart'.
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'package:flutter_login/app.dart'
import 'package:flutter_login/app.dart';
       ^

: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
theme.dart:3
ThemeData appTheme() {
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/action_chip.dart:125:9: Error: Type 'VisualDensity' not found.
  final VisualDensity? visualDensity;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/action_chip.dart:127:9: Error: Type 'MaterialTapTargetSize' not found.
  final MaterialTapTargetSize? materialTapTargetSize;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:398:9: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  final ThemeData? theme;

        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:420:9: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  final ThemeData? darkTheme;
        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:433:9: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  final ThemeData? highContrastTheme;
        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:449:9: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  final ThemeData? highContrastDarkTheme;
        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:914:3: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  ThemeData _themeBuilder(BuildContext context) {
  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar.dart:721:33: Error: Type 'ThemeData' not found.
  bool _getEffectiveCenterTitle(ThemeData theme) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^
```

Keep going like this(its very long)

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Aflutter_login%2Fapp.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:721:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:861:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:660:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
2

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have tried in different projects but even unrelated projects like this one affected by this error.